# Is there a Case invariant way to compare string with a Enum in Enum.IsDefined / Enum.Parse

Tags: c#, enums

So if you don't have access to an Enum or control over a string that is to be compared with enum values, is there a better or cleaner way than the below code to get the value of the Enum that matches and use it in a call to:

```
 Enum.IsDefined() or 
 Enum.Parse()
```

**Example:**

```
  var enumValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof(someType));

  foreach (var value in enumValues) {
        if (value.ToString().ToLowerInvariant() == stringToCompare.ToLowerInvariant()) {
                stringToCompare = value.ToString();
        }
  }
```

Which at this point if there was a match you would have the correct enum value that you could then use in either (Enum.IsDefinied() or Enum.Parse())

Is there a better way than what I defined?

Comment: `enum.Parse` has an overload that can make it case-insensitive.

Comment: But isDefined doesn't, I guess. At least not in 3.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
someType varName = Enum.Parse(typeof(someType), stringToCompare, true);
```

Using this overload of [enum.Parse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxydatf9.aspx)